# How to pass an url generated through selenium (logged in to a website) to the PyQt5 (to create a pdf)?

Tags: python, selenium, pyqt5, html-to-pdf

Basically, I want to log in to the website and generate a pdf of that particular webpage. For login purposes, I am using selenium webdriver (chrome), and to extract pdf I have tried pdfkit, wkhtmltopdf, weasyprint but they are not working as expected (not able to print/create pdf properly).

PyQt5 is using its own HTTP request (which results in creating pdf of login form which is not required) and not able to reach the expected URL (logged in with selenium webdriver).

**selenium webdriver:-**

```
tmp = driver.get(r"https://URL")
```

**PyQt5 piece of code:**

```
loader = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
loader.load(QUrl(tmp))

loader.page().printToPdf("test_profile.pdf", pageLayout=pdfLayout)
```

Comment: what you're expecting from `tmp = driver.get(r"https://URL")` ? bcz it will set `tmp` as `None`. `driver.get` doesn't return.

Comment: Nothing, it was just for reference only. That I was trying to pass `driver.get(r"https://URL")` to the pyqtf functions.

Comment: You cannot pass `driver.get` to `pyqtf` bcz `driver.get` isn't returning anything, moreover I suggest  to see puppeteer. It is selenium like (but asynchronous) API to control chromium /chrome. Also supports to generate pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @FaizanAlHassan, But I'll not be able to use puppeteer because selenium has a lot of options `(find_element_by_*, send_keys for login, can use proxy_server, etc.)` which I cannot bypass. But for sure I'll have a look again at `puppeteer and pyppeteer` and see if that works for me or not. 


I got your point which is true that `driver.get` will not return anything, but any suggestion on how can I force pyqt5 functions\methods to not invoke different webdriver and use the one created by selenium `driver.get`.

Comment: I haven't used pyqt5 `QWebEngineView`, but what I can suggest is if you really need selenium then you should save the page's HTML (with CSS) and find a way to load that into `QWebEngineView` or `pyppeteer`, otherwise for saving pdf `pyppeteer` is more efficient.

Comment: Thank you so much @FaizanAlHassan for suggesting pyppeteer, it solved my problem.

Comment: Really happy to know. Adding this as an answer, so other people can see easily. Please accept that, also upvote the useful comment(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [pyppeteer](https://pyppeteer.github.io/pyppeteer/) (Unofficial Python port of [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/)), its more efficient for saving as PDFs.